# How to add header to child navigators if parent navigators have header mode none in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to know that if we can add header to the child navigators if their parent navigator does have header mode none. I was trying to do this but was unable to bring header to the child navigator if parent have no header.

```
    const MenuStackNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
    All: { screen: AllTweetList },
    Quotes: { screen: QuotesTweetList },
    Blogs: { screen: BlogsTweetList },
    Events: { screen: EventsTweetList },
    Videos: { screen: VideosTweetList },
  },
  {
  tabBarOptions: {
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize:9,
      fontWeight:'900',
    },
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#999999',
    },
    indicatorStyle:{
      height:5,
      backgroundColor:'black'
    }
  },
  navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    },
 });
```

I want a header above this navigator. This navigator is a child of a stack navigator and that stack navigator is child of drawernavigator

Comment: Can you post any sort of code you tried ? What you tried, what happened ?

Comment: See updated one